# only some form element events are being detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

thanks for helping. I have a series of form elements for UI purposes in a web application. I'm using jQuery to create the elements and add listeners. The controls in the #topbar DIV are not being listened to when events occur, but the ones in the #sidebar DIV are. I'm not sure why. Can you help, thank you. Below is the function creating the controls...

```
function constructToolbars(){
        //----------------------------TOPBAR-------------
        //ZONE
        $('#topbar').html('ZONE: ');

        var zoneRadios = ["All", "None"];
        var zoneRadio;
        for(var i=0; i<zoneRadios.length; i+=1){
            zoneRadio = zoneRadios[i];
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'radio',
                id: 'zone' + zoneRadio, name: "zoneRadios", value: zoneRadio,
                checked: zoneRadio === 'All'
                }).appendTo('#topbar');
            $('<label />', {
                'for': 'zone' + zoneRadio, text: zoneRadio
                }).appendTo('#topbar');
        }
        //THIS LISTENER IS NOT TRIGGERED WHEN USER CHANGES
        $( "input:radio[name=zoneRadios]" ).on("change", readRadios);

        var regions = ART.regions;
        var region;
        for(var i=0; i<regions.length; i+=1){
            region = regions[i];
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'checkbox', "class": "zones",
                id: 'zone' + region, name: region, value: region,
                checked: true
                }).appendTo('#topbar');
            $('<label />', {
                'for': 'zone' + region, text: region
                }).appendTo('#topbar');
        }
        //THIS LISTENER IS NOT TRIGGERED WHEN USER CHANGES
        $('.zones').on("change", readToolbars);


        //TIME
        topbar.innerHTML += " ---- TIME: ";
        var timeRadios = ["Current", "Custom"];
        var timeRadio;
        for(var i=0; i<timeRadios.length; i+=1){
            timeRadio = timeRadios[i];
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'radio',
                id: 'time' + timeRadio, name: "timeRadios", value: timeRadio,
                checked: timeRadio === 'Current'
                }).appendTo('#topbar');
            $('<label />', {
                'for': 'time' + timeRadio, text: timeRadio
                }).appendTo('#topbar');
        }
        //THIS LISTENER IS NOT TRIGGERED WHEN USER CHANGES
        $( "input:radio[name=timeRadios]" ).on("change", readRadios);

        topbar.innerHTML += ": ";
        var dateFields = ["From", "To"];
        var dateField;
        for(var i=0; i<dateFields.length; i+=1){
            dateField = dateFields[i];
            $('<label />', {
                'for': 'date' + dateField, text: dateField
                }).appendTo('#topbar');
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'date', "class": "times",
                id: 'date' + dateField, name: dateField, value: "<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y/m/d'))); ?>",
                }).appendTo('#topbar');
        }
        $('<input />', {
            type: 'submit', "class": "times",
            id: 'dateGo', name: 'timeGo', value: 'Go',
            }).appendTo('#topbar');
        //THIS LISTENER IS NOT TRIGGERED WHEN USER CHANGES
        $('.times').on("change", readToolbars);

        //------------------SIDEBAR------------------
        //PLAYERS
        $('<p>',{text: 'PLAYERS'}).appendTo('#sidebar');
        var playerRadios = ["All", "None"];
        var playerRadio;
        for(var i=0; i<playerRadios.length; i+=1){
            playerRadio = playerRadios[i];
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'radio',
                id: 'player' + playerRadio, name: "playerRadios", value: playerRadio,
                checked: playerRadio === 'All'
                }).appendTo('#sidebar');
            $('<label />', {
                'for': 'player' + playerRadio, text: playerRadio
                }).appendTo('#sidebar');
        }
        //add event listener to this set of radio buttons
        $( "input:radio[name=playerRadios]" ).on("change", readRadios);

        var players = [];
        var numReviewers = ART.currentReviewers.length;
        ART.currentReviewers.sort(byAscending('loginName'));
        for (var i=0; i<numReviewers; i+=1){
            players.push(ART.currentReviewers[i].loginName);
        }
        var player;
        for(var i=0; i<numReviewers; i+=1){
            player = players[i];
            $('<br />').appendTo('#sidebar');
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'checkbox', "class": "players",
                id: 'player' + player, name: player, value: player,
                }).appendTo('#sidebar');
            $('<label />', {
                'for': 'zone' + player, text: player
                }).appendTo('#sidebar');
        }
        //add event listener to checkbox elements of this class
        $('.players').on("change", readToolbars);

        //ACTIVITY
        $('<p>',{text: 'ACTIVITY'}).appendTo('#sidebar');
        var activityRadios = ["All", "None"];
        var activityRadio;
        for(var i=0; i<activityRadios.length; i+=1){
            activityRadio = activityRadios[i];
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'radio',
                id: 'activity' + activityRadio, name: "activityRadios", value: activityRadio,
                checked: activityRadio === 'All'
                }).appendTo('#sidebar');
            $('<label />', {
                'for': 'activity' + activityRadio, text: activityRadio
                }).appendTo('#sidebar');
        }
        //add event listener to this set of radio buttons
        $( "input:radio[name=activityRadios]" ).on("change", readRadios);

        var activities = ART.alertCategories;
        activities.unshift("touches");
        var numActivities = activities.length;
        var activity;
        for(var i=0; i<numActivities; i+=1){
            activity = activities[i];
            $('<br />').appendTo('#sidebar');
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'checkbox', "class": "activities",
                id: 'activity' + activity, name: activity, value: activity,
                }).appendTo('#sidebar');
            $('<label />', {
                'for': 'activity' + activity, text: activity
                }).appendTo('#sidebar');
        }
        //add event listener to checkbox elements of this class
        $('.activities').on("change", readToolbars);
    }
```

Comment: No one is going to decrypt that chunk of code for you, please post only the relevant parts and a test case. Doing so might actually help you solve it by yourself...

Comment: Can you point out which events in the code are not triggered? (Just by a comment next to the relevant event listeners fx)

Comment: David, I've done what you've suggested for several hours. At this point, I don't know what the issue is, so I'm posting everything that might be involved. The text of my question was worded to help focus anyone who could help on what I think the problem is, but again, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the lines that actually reset the HTML and hence manipulating the DOM.

`topbar.innerHTML += " ---- TIME: "`
&
`topbar.innerHTML += ": "`

this is actually equivalent to resetting the HTML as

`topbar.innerHTML = topbar.innerHTML + " ---- TIME: "`

Please bind all the events at the end collectively to avoid this situation or use a higher listener like `$('#topbar').on("change", '.zones', readToolbars)`

instead of `$('.zones').on("change", readToolbars)`

Comment: Thanks so much, that was it. Not intuitive for me why the innerHTML += causes this - thank you for pointing it out. Could you recommend a better way for a horizontal layout of these elements?